# Golang use of Zerolog and raising errors

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm using [zerolog](https://github.com/rs/zerolog) to do logging in my Go app, and I'm trying to follow best practices for only erroring out at the top of the stack. However, I'm not sure exactly how to write both to my error log and pass the error up the chain:

```golang
func VeryDeepFunction() (int, error) {
   err := doSomethingThatCouldCauseError()
   if err != nil {
      errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("something bad happened: %+v", err)
      log.Error().Msgf(errMsg)
      return 0, fmt.Errorf(errMsg)
   }
   return 1, nil
}
```

This feels redundant to me - formatting the string, filing with zerolog, and then wrapping the error again. Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: ideally error log will be part of middle ware, which will be called in handler, the handler will log the error, which is returned by layers below.

Comment: oh interesting - so we wrap the error and let the error be both handled and printed at the top of the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to chain errors

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

var someError = errors.New("something is wrong")

func main() {
    // processing error on top level
    if err := someFunc(); errors.Is(err, someError) {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

func someFunc() error {
    if err := alwaysError(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "someFunc")
    }

    return nil
}

func alwaysError() error {
    return someError
}
```

Output will be

```
2022/09/01 10:00:46 someFunc: something is wrong
```

See [errors package](https://github.com/pkg/errors) for details